# Как пометить значения в массиве PHP?

Tags: php

Привет! Есть массив УРЛов, который собирается из массивов поменьше. Если ссылки одинаковые, то они показываются как одна ссылка, т.е. не дублируются Этот массив заносится в таблицу, где пользователь каждому УРЛу назначает свои характеристики. На деле это выглядит как таблица в левой колонке которой УРЛ, а в следующих select значение которого выбирает пользователь. После всех манипуляций строится график на основании выбора юзера. вопрос в том как определить какой УРЛ к какому массиву(который поменьше) относится?

Comment: Предоставьте код, который собирает конечный массив из меньших. На вскидку - добавить ссылку на оригинал в сам массив, попробуйте такой способ `$arr1 = ['foo' => 'bar']; $arr1['_ref'] =& $arr1;`

Comment: Массивы поменьше - не ясно. Добавьте код.